# SQLite error an android: foreign key mismatch on Insert on Database

Tags: android, sqlite

and thanks in advance!
I'm going crazy with an error, when trying to insert in a table that has foreign keys. Values exist, are the same type and are not-null... And the more funny is that first time fails, and only first! The other inserts works perfectly!
I've tried to delete insert and repeat, and the error is not throwed again... Only first time!
I'm trying it on Android 2.2 (Froyo), and before was in 2.1 with no foreign keys.

Sorry for the big "message" but i'm lost!

error:

---

```
03-30 16:59:56.333: E/AndroidRuntime(28007): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: foreign key mismatch: , while compiling: INSERT INTO productoslista(idProducto, idUnidad, comprado, idLista, comentario, cantidad) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
03-30 16:59:56.333: E/AndroidRuntime(28007):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
03-30 16:59:56.333: E/AndroidRuntime(28007):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
03-30 16:59:56.333: E/AndroidRuntime(28007):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
03-30 16:59:56.333: E/AndroidRuntime(28007):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
03-30 16:59:56.333: E/AndroidRuntime(28007):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:36)
03-30 16:59:56.333: E/AndroidRuntime(28007):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)
03-30 16:59:56.333: E/AndroidRuntime(28007):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1536)
03-30 16:59:56.333: E/AndroidRuntime(28007):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1432)
```

tables:

---

```
CREATE TABLE [ProductosLista] (
[idLista] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[idProducto] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[cantidad] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[idUnidad] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[comprado] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[comentario] TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY ([idLista],[idProducto],[comentario]),
FOREIGN KEY (idLista) REFERENCES Listas(idLista),
FOREIGN KEY (idProducto) REFERENCES Productos(idProducto),
FOREIGN KEY (idUnidad) REFERENCES Unidades(idUnidad)



CREATE TABLE [Listas] (
[idLista] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
[descripcion] TEXT  UNIQUE NOT NULL,
[fechaCreacion] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[visible] TEXT  NOT NULL,
[estadoCompra] INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [Unidades] (
[idUnidad] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[idIdioma] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[abreviatura] TEXT  NOT NULL,
[descripcion] TEXT  NOT NULL,
--PRIMARY KEY ([idUnidad],[idIdioma]),
FOREIGN KEY (idIdioma) REFERENCES Idiomas(idIdioma)
);

CREATE TABLE [Productos] (
[idProducto] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
[idPadre] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[idCategoria] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[idTipoAlimentacion] INTEGER NOT NULL,
[eliminado] INTEGER NOT NULL,
[imagen] INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY (idPadre) REFERENCES Productos(idProducto),
FOREIGN KEY (idCategoria) REFERENCES Categorias(idCategoria)
);
```

Comment: why `FOREIGN KEY (idPadre) REFERENCES Productos(idProducto),` within `CREATE TABLE [Productos]`??

Comment: I found the problem, sorry to be too late! I writed it in a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete your database and run the application again. You will delete your database with the emulator open, then open the tab file explorer and go up to the folder where the bank. Sorry for english mistakes I'm Brazilian.

Comment: I found the problem, sorry to be too late! I writed it in a new answer

Answer (score 1):

and sorry to be too late. I resolved this problem modifying table "unidades" to have a single primary key, not one composite. So the error inserting in "productoslista" occurred because a foreign key from "productoslista" was referencing a part of the composite PK of table "unidades"

The problem was that sqlite doesn't like you reference a single field from a composite primary key, so the solution is to have single primary keys and avoid composites.

This last kind of PK is a cause of bad design (I readed a lot of this) so is better to redesign tables to have single PKs, and is not a problem to hace more tables if the design is gonna be more flexible and readable. By the way thanks everybody!